# Where clause on field outside Lambda expression class in Linq

Tags: linq

If I were to use the following code to select products into a Class names Products, how would I be able to add a Where clause enabled=true without adding it to the class Products?

```
        List<Products> lp = db.products.Select(product => new Products
        {
            Name = product.name,
            Description = product.description,
            Category = product.Category
        }).ToList();
```

Adding *.Where(x => x.enabled==true)* doesn't work because *enabled* is not part of the Products class, just part of the *products* table.

Comment: if `enabled` is not a member of the `db.products` class instances, I'm afraid that you can't do what you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    List<Products> lp = db.products
        .Where(p => p.enabled)
        .Select(product => new Products
        {
            Name = product.name,
            Description = product.description,
            Category = product.Category
        }).ToList();
```

Also a good practice advice, I'd name the class in singular form, `Product`.

Comment: Thanks for the good practice advice.  Obviously I'm still learning.

Answer (score 4):

I assume that you have tried to filter the products-list instead of the table. So you jst have to prepend the `Where`. This has also the advantage that you filter in the database instead of in the memory.

```
List<Products> lp = db.products
.Where(p => p.enabled)
.Select(product => new Products
{
    Name = product.name,
    Description = product.description,
    Category = product.Category
}).ToList();
```

Side-note: you should follow .NET naming conventions. For example use pascal case properties or class names. A class should normally be singular, if you want multiple of it's type use a `List<Product>`.

Comment: Sorry I was adding it at the end instead of the correct place.

Comment: @Dave: That's also horribly inefficient even if `Product` would have that property since you would load all products into memory before you'd start filtering.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Products> lp = db.products
    .Where(x => x.enabled==true)
    .Select(product => new Products
    {
        Name = product.name,
        Description = product.description,
        Category = product.Category
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Or better, `x => x.enabled`, I'd suggest. (I don't like comparisons with Boolean true/false values if I can help it.)

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Products> lp = db.products.Where(product => product.enabled).
    Select(product => new Products
    {
        Name = product.name,
        Description = product.description,
        Category = product.Category
    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var filter1 = Enumerable.Range(0, 50).Where(c => c % 2 == 0).Select(c => c).ToList();

Console.WriteLine(filter1[3]);

filter1.Insert(4, 13);

foreach (var v in filter1)
{
  Console.WriteLine(v);
}
```

Comment: A chunk of code is not a very informative answer. Please can you add a paragraph to your question, explaining why your code fixes the problem?